# Word Wall of Whimsical Wordy Whatchamacallits

Tags: word, knowledge, word-ladder

I was making a **particularly** difficult word wall, when I misplaced all the words for it. Luckily, I still had the clues. However, poring through the clues, I realised that I had **nine** clues, yet my word wall had **eight**? Above all, I couldn't remember the words, so I couldn't remove the faulty clue. You'll just have to solve it for yourself.

***Clue list:***

> reverse effect
>
> alder trees
>
> wavy
>
> limbs
>
> asian legume
>
> curves
>
> resembling a cross
>
> battalion
>
> vases

**Your task is to assemble the definitions of 8 of these clues so that it forms
a word ladder. One of the clues is fake, made to ruin your day. Enjoy!**

However, I remembered that I had a hint towards solving this - and this was the hint:

> **This puzzle does not have an accent.**

Hopefully you have better luck than I did!

**EDIT** for clarification:

> All these words are in Merriam-Webster Dictionary
>
> You may not change the length of the word in any way.
>
> You may not change the same letter position twice in a row.

Comment: Are the words all the same length? There are many types of word ladders, you should explain how this one works (i.e. can I add or subtract letters? Or only swap?)

Comment: should it be waves instead of wavy?

Comment: tough puzzle but enjoyed it! +1ed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is hard because it uses a lot of rare words...

```
reverse effect
```

> undo

```
alder trees
```

> [arns](https://www.wordplays.com/crossword-solver/alder)

```
wavy (should be waves??)
```

> undy (thanks @RShields)

```
limbs
```

> arms

```
asian legume
```

> [urds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigna_mungo)

```
curves
```

> arcs `the fake one`

```
resembling a cross
```

> [urdy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urdy) (thanks @RShields)

```
battalion
```

> army

```
vases
```

> [urns](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/urn)

The ladder

> army -> arms -> arns -> urns -> urds -> urdy -> undy -> undo

Comment: This is close, but the word is meant to mean wavy.

Comment: are the other words fine except the wavy one? @XDVV

Comment: no, read the rules i add for clarification

Comment: base64(dXJkcyAtPiB1cmR5IC0+IHVuZHkgLT4gdW5kbw==)

Comment: rot13(naq nepf vf gur snxr orpnhfr jvgubhg vg, lbh qba'g punatr gur fnzr yrggre gjvpr)

Comment: this should be better, please check, thanks @XDVV

Comment: Don’t you need to change two letters to get from word 4 to word 5?

Comment: Well done! I thought it might have taken a bit longer!

Comment: @XDVV what actually does the hint mean? thanks